# Trying to start a bash script from autostart

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, chrome, autostart

I am trying to start a script which starts the browser in full screen mode and refreshes the pages every 24 hours from the autostart file.
I created the file `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

which includes the following lines

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile --LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@sh /home/pi/start_browser.sh
```

I tried the last line in all possible variations, directly, with sudo, without the `@`.

If I start the browser directly from there, i.e.:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile --LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
chromium-browser --kiosk https://google.com
```

it runs, I think the script is not being executed, (logs don't get printed) the path is correct though.

What do you think could be the issue?
I've pieced this together from various SO posts and tutorials.

Many thanks in advance.

Oli

Comment: Welcome, try using the full path of `sh`, for example `/usr/bin/sh`. You can check which is running `which sh`.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity thank you! so like `/urs/bin/sh /home/pi/start_browser.sh` ?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I did that already, forgot to mention it apologies, no difference